# How to access meteor.users profile

Tags: meteor, meteor-collections

I am trying to simply query the name of a user given the _id like so;

```
profile = Meteor.users.find({_id: userId}, {fields: {"profile" : 1}});
```

EDIT**

The userId will come from a url parameter (I'm using it to route to user profile pages)

Assuming there is a "name" field in the profile, I would assume calling profile.name would give the name of the user. But it shows profile.name is undefined. console.log(profile) shows [object Object]. I've also tried

```
name = Meteor.users.find({_id: userId}, {fields: {"profile.name" : 1}});
```

but this yields the same thing, console.log(name) -> [object Object]
name.name -> undefined (in case it returned an object like {name: "jon doe"} i would call name.name)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just need `Meteor.user().profile.name`. See the duplicated question for more details. Also see the "find and fetch" section of [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) for why the above isn't working.

Comment: I edited the question, but what I'm trying to do is be able to display a user's profile page, regardless of who is logged in... so I cannot always use `Meteor.user().profile.name` I must be able to query any user's profile at any given time. I also tried `profile = Meteor.users.find({_id: userId}, {fields: {"profile" : 1}}).fetch();` it didnt work either

Comment: You should use `findOne` if you want a single document. Try `var profile = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: userId }).profile;`